# Use variable's value as variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, variables

I have a variable with a value, let's say

```
var myVarMAX = 5;
```

In HTML I have an element with `id="myVar"`.

I combine the `id` with the string MAX (creating a string `myVarMAX`). My question is how can I use this string to access a variable with the same name?

Comment: It's evil but you're looking for eval. ;)

Comment: I don't think that this is entirely clear. You already have a variable `myVarMAX`, then you combine `"myVar"` with `MAX` (what's that?) to form `myVarMAX` again? Why aren't you using arrays?

Comment: @Tomalak - he could have many vars with suffixes matching various IDs. Anyway, an associative array is of course how to do this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You COULD use eval, but if you have the var in the window scope, this is better

```
var myVarMAX = 5;
var id="MAX"; // likely not in a var

alert(window["myVar"+id]); // alerts 5
```

However [Don't pollute the global scope!](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/JavaScript+Best+Practices#JavaScriptBestPractices-Don%27tpollutetheglobalscope!)

A better solution is something like what is suggested in the link I posted

```
var myVars = {
  "myVarMin":1,
  "myVarMax":5,
  "otherVarXX":"fred"
} // notice no comma after the last var
```

then you have

alert(myVars["myVar"+id]);

Comment: Good answer. I wasn't expecting eval to be the only option. I am glad there is an unevil way to do this.

Comment: Except polluting the global scope is ALSO considered evil, so this is the lesser of two evils

Comment: Idd. I should have said 'uneviler'. :)

Comment: Or just "less evil". The proper solution here is to design your program correctly so that you do not have to do this at all. Use arrays.

Answer (score -1):

Since this post is referred to often, I would like to add a use case.

It is probably often a PHP programmer who gives Javascript/Nodejs a try, who runs into this problem.

```
// my variables in PHP
$dogs  = [...]; //dog values
$cats  = [...]; //cat values
$sheep = [...]; //sheep values
```

Let's say I want to save them each in their own file (dogs.json, cats.json, sheep.json), not all at the same time, without creating functions like savedogs, savecats, savesheep. An example command would be  `save('dogs')`

In PHP it works like this:

```
function save($animal) {
    if(!$animal) return false;
    file_put_contents($animal.'.json', json_encode($$animal));
    return true;
}
```

In Nodejs/Javascript it could be done like this

```
// my variables in NodeJS/Javascript
let dogs  = [...]; //dog values
let cats  = [...]; //cat values
let sheep = [...]; //sheep values

function save(animal) {
    if (!animal) return false;

    let animalType = {};
    animalType.dogs  = dogs;
    animalType.cats  = cats;
    animalType.sheep = sheep;    

    fs.writeFile(animal + '.json', JSON.stringify(animalType[animal]), function (err){
       if (err) return false;
    });
    return true;

}
```