# How to dynamically fetch JSON based on param in express

Tags: json, express, fetch

I'm new to node and express but trying to dynamically fetch JSON based on the user's language settings. I need to figure out how to serve up the params:

I was thinking to try and set the "lang" param to its own variable and return that, but I am reading on SO that this is not best practice: [Use variable's value as variable in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401915/use-variables-value-as-variable-in-javascript)

```
var express = require("express");
var english = require('./Data/english.json');
var spanish = require('./Data/spanish.json'); 
var app = express();


app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('inside of app.use');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-    
  With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.get("/:lang", function (req, res, next) {
  const lang = req.params.lang;
  console.log(lang)
  res.send(lang);
});


app.listen(5000, () => console.log('Listening on port 5000!'))
```

I would like to be able to dynamically return the appropriate json file ! Any thoughts much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

- Use the [fs module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to read you JSON files
- Call `JSON.parse()` to parse the raw JSON
- Choose the file according to `var lang = req.params.lang` using some kind of logic (for example, `'spanish' -> './data/spanish.json'`)

## Code

```js
const fs = require('fs');

// Supported languages
const supportedLanguages = ['english', 'spanish'];

app.get("/:lang", function (req, res, next) {
  const lang = req.params.lang;

  if (supportedLanguages.indexOf(lang) === -1) {
    res.status(400).send('Language not supported');
  } else {
    fs.readFile(`./Data/${lang}.json`, (err, data) => {
      // If error send a 500 status
      if (err) res.status(500).send(err);

      // Else parse the JSON file and send it
      else res.send(JSON.parse(data));
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple to return json data with express.

Just use  `res.json({key: value , key2: value2})` instead of  `res.send`

In your case, you can

```
const language = req.params.lang;
res.json({lang: lang})
```

you will receive a JSON object instead of text

Comment: that just returns {lang: "english} - I want to return the imported file at the top (either var english = require('./Data/english.json'); or var spanish = require('./Data/spanish.json'); ) based on the params